# Show line and points in 3 axis in Java

Tags: java

I have 100 point in 3D and all of them are connected with each other via a segment line. 
I want to show points and connecting lines in 3D axis(x,y,z) in Java.

I read some answers and I saw java 3D and JavaFX Scene Builder but they were so sophisticated.
I used to work with MATLAB. It provides really simple tools to show such things.

Is there any possible simple way or library in Java to do so?

Please don't refer to strange and sophisticated projects.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use ``JAVA 3D API`` for this purpose. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I know about JAVA 3D. It's huge library and I don't have time to learn about it.
I just need a simple way and some commands to draw coordinate axes system, points and lines just like what we do in MATLAB.